# rspec without rails - unitialized constant

Tags: ruby, rspec

I cannot figure out how to get rspec to work without rails

```
root
--lib/
----information.rb
--spec/
----spec_helper.rb
----information_spec.rb
.rspec
.ruby-version
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
```

spec_helper.rb (after `rspec --init` and me trying different things)

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'rspec'
Dir["../lib/**/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }

RSpec.configure do |config|
# The settings below are suggest...
...
end
```

information_spec.rb

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'  

RSpec.describe Information do
    it 'describes stuff' do
        expect(true).to be(true)
    end
end
```

information.rb

```
class Information
end
```

console output

```
~ rspec 
~/spec/information_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Information (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your spec:

```
require 'information'
```